# derivative of an exponential function with respect to $\beta$

Tags: derivatives

If my $$ f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n }x_i -  \frac{\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}x_ie^{x_i\beta}}{\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}e^{x_i\beta}}$$

What is the first derivative of this function with respect to $\beta$ ?

Comment: Why do you have $\beta_p$ instead of $\beta$?

Comment: The derivative of the first term is $0$. For the second, use the quotient rule and the chain rules on each summand . (Assuming $\beta = \beta_p$.)

Comment: @martycohen, thanks marty fixed it,

Comment: @EthanBolker, thanks Ethan I will try that.

Comment: What is $t_i$? What is $R_i$?

Comment: The way you've written this, the answer is zero, because summing something over $t_i\in R_i$ when there's no $t_i$ anywhere in the "something" is the same as multiplying by $\lvert R_i\rvert$. After doing the obvious cancellations you no longer have anything dependent on $\beta.$ I suspect the formula you wrote is not the one you want.

Comment: If you can resolve the other issues already mentioned regarding your formula, also be careful about the grouping of summation terms. I would normally have thought you meant to take a sum of $x_i$ and then subtract the ratio of two other sums, but that would leave $i$ as a free term so maybe you meant the first summation to apply to the entire expression on the right. If so, some well-placed parentheses would clarify whether you meant $(\sum x_i) - \ldots$ or $\sum(x_i - \ldots).$

Comment: @the_candyman, David, $t_i$ and $R(t_i)$ are irrelevant as far as taking the derivative of $f(x)$ w.r.t $\beta$ is concerned. I think !!!. Also I could explain what they represent but it might be off-topic and derail the question.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that
you meant $\beta$
instead of $\beta_p$.

If
$f(\beta) 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n }x_i -  
\dfrac{\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}x_ie^{x_i\beta}}{\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}e^{x_i\beta}}
$,
then we
just apply standard rules
of differentiation.

Writing $b$ for $\beta$,
$f(b) 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n }x_i -  
\dfrac{\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}x_ie^{x_ib}}{\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}e^{x_ib}}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n }x_i -  
\dfrac{g(b)}{h(b)}
$,
where
$g(b)
=\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}x_ie^{x_ib}
$
and
$h(b)
=\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}e^{x_ib}
$.

Then
$f'(b)
=-\dfrac{g'(b)h(b)-g(b)h'(b)}{h^2(b)}
$.

The answer is then
given by
$g'(b)
=\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}x_i^2e^{x_ib}
$
and
$h'(b)
=\sum_{t_i\in(R_i)}x_ie^{x_ib}
$.

Nothing complicated.

Comment: ,Marty is the numerator of $f'(b)$ = 0 ?

Comment: No. It's a double sum because each of g. h. g', and h' are sums.